# How to get name of a task owner from the _ref?

Tags: javascript, rally

I have this code that iterates over tasks:

```
Ext.Array.each(data, function(task) {
    var t  = {
        FormattedID: task.get('FormattedID'),
        Name: task.get('Name'),
        Estimate: task.get('Estimate'),
        Owner: task.get('Owner')._ref,
    };
}
```

I can get it print `/user/1234`

but this does not work:

```
Owner: task.get('Owner').UserName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `task.get('Owner')._refObjectName` as in the code fragment below:

```
Ext.Array.each(data, function(task) {
                            var t  = {
                                FormattedID: task.get('FormattedID'),
                                Name: task.get('Name'),
                                Estimate: task.get('Estimate'),
                               Owner: task.get('Owner')._refObjectName
                            };
```